# Div not stretching in basic example

Tags: html, stretch

I have a site that I need various divs within to stretch to the height of various dynamic content. From what I understand all surrounding/parent divs need to be 100% height in order for the 100% height to work on child divs.

I added 100% to html and the body css and everything went terrible.
I have spend much time trying to research and solve this issues and got it down to a very basic failed example.

Can anyone explain why

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<style>
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:100%; background-color:#00ff00;">
    <div style="height:3000px; border:2px solid #ff0000;">
        <br style="clear:both;" />
    </div><br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

does not behave as I would assume? I would expect the inner div to stretch the parent div. I do not understand why this is the case. Can someone explain this to me or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After ten years of programming web applications, it's still confusing for me WHY is it like this every time. I've seen this problem against many programmers. The explanation is so simple.

In HTML, layout system has a main CSS option named `display`. There are two main values for `display` options that change everything on whatever you wanna see in the output. First value is `block`, second is `inline`, and a third one that is combination of mentioned values, `inline-block`. When `display` value of some element is block, it blocks everything horizontally and no element be placed next to it. However there is no option for `height` to do the same.

As far as I know, when you set the `height` value to `100%` you have to calculate margins and border widths in your value MANUALLY!, and the problem is when you set the value of `width` property to `100%` for body, the default value of `margin` in body element is not '0'! and the outputs looks like shit, cause it's stupidly scrolling. So you must set the `margin` to '0' (on the 'body' element).

Also another problem is when you did the margin thing and scroll got fixed, for sure you should set the 'overflow' property of 'body' element to `hidden` or `visible`, and NOT 'scroll' that is the default value for 'display' option. it a backdoor for the height calculation tolerance! You will see it yourself in the output.

For sure, I don't prefer to use 'clear' property for any elements, and also using a relevant 'DOCTYPE' (like HTML4) at the first line for compatibility issues would be better.

Here is the edited version:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body
            {
                height: 100%;

                margin:0;

                overflow:hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height: 100%; background-color: #00ff00;">
            <div style="height: 100%; border: 2px solid #ff0000;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not seem to solved my problem. I need the innner div to stretch with content. In turn in need to allow user to see all the content. In the example above I am unable to see the border at the bottom on the inner div. It appears that both divs are the same size as the viewing area in browser (IE 100% height). The inner one is slight bigger due to the border, hence I would need the other div (green one) to stretch to fix the inner div. For example if the inner div was full on content I would need the green to stretch to fit end I need to be able to scroll through the content.